# How can I get the information from the details tab of the file properties dialog in Windows?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

If you right click a file in Windows explorer and select Properties, a dialog pops up with a ton of information.  How can I access this information using C#?

Specifically, I'm looking for the information on the Details tab.  I'm working mostly with images, so "Date taken" is important. I'll be working with other files as well, so it would be nice to have a way to get any metadata associated with the file.

I've seen places mention using Shell32.dll to get this information, but I get errors when I try to reference this library.  Is there another way to do this, maybe through P/Invoke?

Comment: An Image isn't the same as a regular file. Try loading the Image into an Image object and seeing what it will output for the PropertyItems property. I believe it is a collection of byte arrays so you will need to use the Encoding namespace to get the string value from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around a little, here is a VERY limited example of how to get the image meta data.

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\your\image\here");

        foreach (var a in image.PropertyItems)
        {
            dynamic value;

            switch (a.Type)
                {
                case 2:
                    value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a.Value);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = BitConverter.ToInt16(a.Value, 0);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    value = BitConverter.ToInt32(a.Value, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    value = "NaN";
                    break;
                }

            Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} \r\n Value: {1}", a.Type, value);
        }
```

You can find some more information on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx) and search on the Image Metadata specifications to fully write one yourself.

There is always the option of using a third-party library that already handles this, but I don't do much work in the area of images myself.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. Do you know if there is a way to access similar data in other types of files as well?

Comment: There isn't a one-fit solution. Just like image meta data, all files store their meta data in a different way and format.  In order to do it, you would have to find the specification for the file you want and use an existing library or make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the FileSystemInfo class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx

Comment: Yes. But it's not giving me the information I want. The file I'm testing with says "Created: January-24-13, 11:17:30 AM" on the General tab in Explorer, but says "Date taken 12/09/2012 10:28 PM" on the Details tab. I guess I have to update the question a bit to make this more clear.

Comment: Its strange :/ May be the pproblem is something else or the information is incorrect. Becuase these methods gets the information associated with the file.

Comment: when you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx in your code, what does it return exactly @Tester101?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File` class methods for this purpose:

```
File.GetCreationTime(filename)
File.GetLastWriteTime(filename)
File.GetLastAccessTime(filename)
//and many more in the intellisense
```

Comment: Please see comment on previous answer, and the updated question.